# Toad truncates trailing "0" decimal digits regardless of precision

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm using Toad 12.6 for Oracle and when I try to pull a field whose data type is `Decimal(5,2)`, Toad truncates the decimal for any trailing `0` decimal digits at the end of a number.

For example:

```
 expected -> toad actual 
 5.40     ->  5.4    *incorrect
 1.34     ->  1.34   *correct
 10.24    ->  10.24  *correct
 30.07    ->  30.07  *correct
```

There are a lot of threads about Toad truncating/rounding data when numbers are too large, and that's solved by telling it not to show large numbers with scientific notation.

Is there a setting I haven't found yet which will force Toad to display these trailing digits up to the precision? I would appreciate not having to manually cast a number field (`to_char()` or `to_number()`) every time I want to display uniform results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no such setting in TOAD.

If it were **SQL*Plus**, you'd use `SET` command, e.g.

```
SQL> set numformat 999G990D00
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 5.40 from dual union all
  3     select 1.34 from dual
  4    )
  5  select col from test;

        COL
-----------
       5,40
       1,34

SQL>
```

TOAD is not SQL*Plus. **However**, if you put (literally) this into TOAD's Editor window and press **F5**, you'll get a desired result in its **Output tab**:

```
set numformat 999G990D00

with test (col) as
  (select 5.40 from dual union all
   select 1.34 from dual
  )
select col from test;
```

The result will be

```
        COL
-----------
       5,40
       1,34

2 rows selected.
```

Just to emphasize:

- press F5, not F9, Shift+F9, Ctrl+Enter - nope; press **F5**
- result isn't displayed in the Data Grid tab (but the **Output** tab)

There's a good chance that you won't like that approach. In that case, I believe that `TO_CHAR` is your savior.

Comment: Thanks! I wish there was a solution that didn't require me to reset the number format for each precision or require casting, but that's just how it is

Comment: You're welcome. Just a suggestion: try SQL Developer. It is designed by Oracle, and it is a free tool (as opposed to TOAD). SQL*Plus commands work there so - maybe you'll like it. Doesn't cost much to try it.

Comment: If only! Work environment.

Comment: I see; though, as I've said: it is completely free (to download and use it), so - all it takes is to *download* it, extract ZIP into some folder (there's no installation) and run it. It can't harm anything.

Comment: Finagling the connections might take a bit of work but thats definitely an interesting idea, thanks :)